# Host .NET app inside HTML web page

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe

The main page of our website is HTML.  The powers that be want to put an asp.net calendar on this main page.  Is there any better way to accomplish this than to use an iframe?

Comment: Why can't you convert the page?

Comment: An `<asp:Calendar>`? That clumsy server-side thing? I'm sure you can come up with a good excuse not to use it. Hell, style a jQuery UI DatePicker to look like one, they won't be able to tell the difference

Comment: @Daniel: In short ... because I was told "no."  If I need to recommend using iframes, then OK.  I just wanted to make sure there wasn't another way, short of converting the page, to make this happen.

Comment: @Matti: I believe they actually want to use an Infragistics calendar.  I like the JQuery idea that you, Sohnee, and James suggested.  I'll bring that to the team responsible for this and see how they like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this...

```
<div id="calendar">
    <a href="/calendar/">View our calendar</a>
</div>
```

Then use an AJAX request to replace the link with the actual calendar... works whether or not JavaScript is enabled / successfully fires!

Here is the jQuery way of getting the calendar...

```
 $("#calendar").load("/ajax/calendar/");
```

I recommend that the first URL (the link to the calendar) links to a full page containing the calendar and the second URL (the link to ajax/calendar/) links to something that just returns the HTML for the calendar, to make it faster and less bulky...

All URLs are fictitious and any resemblance to your real URLs is purely coincidental.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it is the general idea I recommended to the team.  Use a jQuery datepicker in inline mode to display the calendar.  Handle the onMonthYearChanged event to execute a ajax call to get the list of events for the new month and then go through the days highlighting the dates that have events scheduled.  I made up a brief demo and it works quite nicely.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you control IIS - you could just map .HTML to the ASP.NET handler and add your asp:calender wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use JavaScript, then I would recommend one of the plethora of JavaScript calendars out there.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Actually, we will need to get calendar data from a database, and AJAX would be nice for this.  You wouldn't know of a sample that uses database data to populate a jQuery calendar, would you?

Comment: I don't know of such an example, but surely someone has done it before. :]